# how to distinguish between value zero and blank cells in conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets-formula, formula, conditional-formatting

The Title explains everything
=$N4=0 < using this custom formula to conditional format a range but the cells that are empty also gets formatted

what can we do for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=($N4=0)*($N4<>"")
```

not sure what the specifics are but within the *Format Rules* you could also directly use '**is equals to**' instead of opting for '*custom formula*'

Comment: Thanks it worked,
cant use **is equal to** because i want to format complete row.

also can bit explain the above code 
I want to understand * and $N4<>""

Comment: * is the AND operator looking for zero and avoid blanks in the range